# Vue fetch gets called twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, fetch-api

I have this code snippet:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "filter",
  props: {},
  setup() {
    const states = useCounterStore();
    return { states };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/tags")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.items = data;
    alert(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  },
});
```

The fetch gets called twice, and I don't know why.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. The obvious explanation is that this component is rendered twice

Comment: I take it you only use the `filter` component once? what makes you say the fetch is called twice though? is the alert firing twice (don't use `alert` for debugging, use `console.log`)

Comment: Does the "options API" even have a `setup` method?

Comment: There are two **.then** is that correct? I always use only one **.then**

Comment: @AlexandreHeinen, it's fetch, not axios, so `res.json` returns a promise, and requires another `.then` to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

From the shared code, it looks like the component is getting mounted twice, so you might need to look into the component that is mounting it.

However, you could store the response so the fetch is not made multiple times

```js
const tags = ref(null);
const tagsError = ref(null);
const getTags = () => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/tags")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      tags.value = data;
      return tags;
    })
    .catch((err) => tagsError.value = err.message;
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: "filter",
  props: {},
  setup() {
    const states = useCounterStore();
    if(tags.value === null) {
      getTags().then(() => this.items = [...tags.value]);
    } else {
      this.items = [...tags.value];
    }
    return { states };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {},
});
```

because `tags` is declared outside of the component, it will behave like a global, so it will be stateful. Every time the component is `setup`, it will check whether the tags are loaded then either use the cached data, or load it and update the items after.

A couple notes about the example...
Ideally, such logic would be in a separate file and have better abstraction. For example, if you have multiple APIs they could share this function, eg. `const {state, data, error} = useApiCall('/tags')`. And instead of using `items`, because the tags in the example is a `ref` already, you could use `tags` directly. There is also a possibility of a race condition that could be solved by tracking the API call state.